# Binarize a python list based on previous value

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I want to binarize python list based on previous value, output should be 1 if previous value is lower, and 0 if higher. Example:

```
[18985.0, 20491.0, 18554.0, 14241.0, 13390.0, 14965.0,]
```

should become:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension should work.

```
A = [18985.0, 20491.0, 18554.0, 14241.0, 13390.0, 14965.0]
A = [0] + [1 if A[i] > A[i-1] else 0  for i in range(1, len(A))]
```

You might want to consider the case when two values are equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension along with `zip` function to achieve your desired result. I am hardcoding first value to be `0` since there is no previous value to compare

```
>>> [0] + [1 if i<j else 0 for i,j in zip(l, l[1:])]
>>> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` solution:

```
 vals = [18985.0, 20491.0, 18554.0, 14241.0, 13390.0, 14965.0]
 map(
     lambda (ind, x): 
     1 if vals[ind] > vals[ind - 1] and ind != 0 else 0, 
     enumerate(vals)
 )
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `inf` as an appropriate default value for the first comparison (it will never be `<` any number), and use use `itertools.chain` to create an appropriate iterator that starts at `inf` then gives you the previous item in your data. This can be nice and concise with `map` and the `operator` module if you don't mind `bool` objects as your result:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> inf = float('inf')
>>> import operator as op
>>> list(map(op.lt, data, chain((inf,), data)))
[True, False, True, True, True, False]
```

This could be done with a list-comprehension using `zip` as well, although, it starts to get clunky:

```
>>> [prev < curr for curr, prev in zip(data, chain((inf,), data))]
[False, True, False, False, False, True]
```

But it allows for more convenient conversion to `int`:

```
>>> [int(prev < curr) for curr, prev in zip(data, chain((inf,), data))]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```